# there is no type juggling for constants (I want my string 'REGEX_NAME' like 'REGEX_EMAIL' to become REGEX_NAME like REGEX_EMAIL)

Tags: php, constants

I'm having to manually write:

```
if($pattern == 'REGEX_EMAIL') $pattern = REGEX_EMAIL;
if($pattern == 'REGEX_PASSWORD') $pattern = REGEX_PASSWORD;
```

Is there an other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`constant` function](http://php.net/constant) to get the constant’s value by its name:

```
if (substr($pattern, 0, 6) == 'REGEX_' && defined($pattern)) {
    $pattern = constant($pattern);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution (albeit ridiculous) would be to use an associative array...

```
$regexs = array('REGEX_NAME' => REGEX_NAME, 'REGEX_EMAIL' => REGEX_EMAIL);
```

Comment: +1 This is a good solution if you want to restrict the set of *REGEX\_…* constants.